# Is there a way for 'jq' to read json with single quotes instead of double?

Tags: sed, json, jq

I use `jq` as an efficient way to parse out large nested `json` files. I sometimes want to us `jq` with a `json` formatted file which has single quotes instead of double around keys and values like below:

```
{
  'aggs': {
    'two': {
      'composite': {
        'size': 700
       }
     }
  }
}
```

I know this is not considered an actual `json` format, but I was wondering if jq has some parameters I could set to read this since otherwise it is not able to read this file.

If not, what is the most efficient way in linux to replace all single quotes to double so it is readable by `jq`

Comment: I think single quotes are acceptable in yaml. Yaml tries to be a superset of json.  You could try [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq#:~:text=yq%20uses%20jq%20like%20syntax,you%20are%20good%20to%20go!)

Answer (score 10):

Using single quotes for the keys, or strings in general, is breaking [the JSON format specification](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), but we may instead interpret the document as a YAML document containing literal (single-quoted) strings.

[Mike Farah's `yq`](https://mikefarah.github.io/yq/) is able to parse it as YAML (with caveats mentioned below), and to convert it into standard JSON:

```bash
$ yq -oj eval . file
{
  "aggs": {
    "two": {
      "composite": {
        "size": 700
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that it will convert `'1"2'` correctly into `"1\"2"`, but that it does not handle `'1\'2'` (it gives an error, but that's not strange as the string would be an invalid string in YAML too).  Since backslashes are literal in single-quoted YAML strings, this means that it converts `'1\"2'` into `"1\\\"2"`.

Since backslashes are literal backslashes, it might not do what you want with strings containing other already encoded values, such as literal newlines encoded as `\n` or literal tabs encoded as `\t`, translating these into `\\n` and `\\t` respectively.

[Andrey Kislyuk's `yq`](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/) (which is a wrapper around `jq`) seems to have the same restrictions and caveats as Mike's `yq`:

```bash
$ yq . file
{
  "aggs": {
    "two": {
      "composite": {
        "size": 700
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Stephen Levine's `yj`](https://github.com/sclevine/yj), can also be used to convert the data from YAML to JSON:

```bash
$ yj <file
{"aggs":{"two":{"composite":{"size":700}}}}
```

Answer (score 6):

If in those files quotes are escaped just like json does (prepending `\`), then you could translate the quotes with `tr` before feeding the document to `jq` with something like this:

```
cat file_with_single_quotes | tr "'" '"' | jq ...
```

or the simpler:

```
tr "'" '"' < file_with_single_quotes | jq ...
```

For the text in your question:

```
$ tr "'" '"' < file_sq | jq .aggs.two
{
  "composite": {
    "size": 700
  }
}
```